# Python web scraping, program won't start

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm a Java and C# developer and learning Python (web scraping, specific) at the moment. When I try to start my script (just double-clicking on it) it won't open. The terminal opens for a few milliseconds and then closes. What mistake did I make?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

product_all_pages = []

for i in range(1,15):
    response = requests.get("https://www.bol.com/nl/s/?page={i}&searchtext=hand+sanitizer&view=list")
    content = response.content
    parser = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    body = parser.body
    producten = body.find_all(class_="product-item--row js_item_root")
    product_all_pages.extend(producten)
    
len(product_all_pages)

price = float(product_all_pages[1].meta.get('content'))
productname = product_all_pages[1].find(class_="product-title--inline").a.getText()
print(price)
print(productname)

productlijst = []

for item in product_all_pages:
    if item.find(class_="product-prices").getText() == '\nNiet leverbaar\n':
        price = None
    else:
        price = float(item.meta['content'])
    product = item.find(class_="product-title--inline").a.getText()
    productlijst.append([product, price])
    
print(productlijst[:3])

df = pd.DataFrame(productlijst, columns=["Product", "price"])
print(df.shape)
df["price"].describe()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running your code from command line, then you can see the debugging output. Your code throws an `AttributeError` because `content` contains no data. The problem is that the url is not formatted because you didn't initiate f-string formatting. This should work:

```
response = requests.get(f"https://www.bol.com/nl/s/?page={i}&searchtext=hand+sanitizer&view=list")
```